# compile error: 'head' does not name a type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm currently making a spaghetti mess that I call snake game and I ran into a problem.
I defineda struct snakeSeg and below a head pointer, now the problem is at the initialisation not
at declaring the pointer within itself.
Take a look:
'''

```
struct snakeSeg
{
    int snakeX;
    int snakeY;
    snakeSeg *next;
};

    snakeSeg *head = new snakeSeg;
    head->next = NULL;  //<-----Here's the problem that I ran into
    head->snakeX = 15;
    head->snakeY = 15;
```

'''
If anybody had any idea what's wrong I'd love to read your input.
Cheers!

Comment: Is that code outside of a function?

Comment: Pretty much the only thing you can do outside of a function is define and initialize.

Comment: There is a list of decent books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code was outside of main.

```
struct snakeSeg
{
    int snakeX;
    int snakeY;
    snakeSeg *next;
};

int main()
{
    snakeSeg *head = new snakeSeg;
    head->next = nullptr; // it is better to use nullptr
    head->snakeX = 15;
    head->snakeY = 15;


    delete head; // also you need to free the memory
    return 0;
}
```

You can have it as a global variable like this:

```
struct snakeSeg
{
    int snakeX;
    int snakeY;
    snakeSeg *next;
};

snakeSeg *head = new snakeSeg; // all the rest of the code needs to be in a function
```

Another way to do this is the way @StoryTeller suggested in the comments:

```
struct snakeSeg
{
    int snakeX;
    int snakeY;
    snakeSeg *next;
};

snakeSeg *head = new snakeSeg{15, 15, nullptr};
```

Comment: So by what you're saying you can only declare outside main and the rest should be done in a function? I'm asking because I want the head to be a global variable for ease of use even though it's bad practice.

Comment: @DedHorse I updated my answer.

Comment: You don't need a function here, not really. `snakeSeg *head = new snakeSeg{15, 15, nullptr};`